# AWS S3 Cloudormation updating stack fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template for S3 and I'm trying to create it once and then update it. But when i try to update it it fails with the error message `<bucket_name> already exists in stack <arn:id>`.

```
    "S3Bucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
        "Properties": {
            "AccessControl": "BucketOwnerFullControl",
            "BucketName": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "-",
                    [
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "VPCInfo",
                                "VPCname"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Ref": "BucketName"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "LoggingConfiguration": {
                "DestinationBucketName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "VPCInfo",
                                    "VPCname"
                                ]
                            },
                            "-s3logs"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "LogFilePrefix": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "-",
                        [
                            {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "VPCInfo",
                                    "VPCname"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "VersioningConfiguration": {
                "Status": "Enabled"
            }
        }
    }
```

Second try update where `BucketName & TopicName` are passed as params

```
    "S3Bucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
        "Properties": {
            "AccessControl": "BucketOwnerFullControl",
            "BucketName": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "-",
                    [
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "VPCInfo",
                                "VPCname"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Ref": "BucketName"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "LoggingConfiguration": {
                "DestinationBucketName": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "VPCInfo",
                                    "VPCname"
                                ]
                            },
                            "-s3logs"
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "LogFilePrefix": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "-",
                        [
                            {
                                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                    "VPCInfo",
                                    "VPCname"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            "NotificationConfiguration": {
                "TopicConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "Topic": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:sns:",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                    },
                                    ":",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                                    },
                                    ":function:",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "TopicName"
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
                        "Filter": {
                            "S3Key": {
                                "Rules": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "suffix",
                                        "Value": {
                                            "Ref": "FileSuffix"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Topic": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:sns:",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                    },
                                    ":",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                                    },
                                    ":function:",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "TopicName"
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "Event": "s3:ObjectRemoved:*",
                        "Filter": {
                            "S3Key": {
                                "Rules": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "suffix",
                                        "Value": {
                                            "Ref": "FileSuffix"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "VersioningConfiguration": {
                "Status": "Enabled"
            }
        }
    }
```

What's the correct way to update S3 stack? The reason why I'm trying to do it twice is due to this -> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are deleting the CFT and recreating it. Your problem is         `"DeletionPolicy": "Retain"` which retains the S3 bucket even after you delete the CFT. If you update the existing one, you should be fine.

Just delete the bucket manually if you delete CFT or change         `"DeletionPolicy": "Retain"` to `"DeletionPolicy": "Delete"`